# Use SQL Server 2012 as DB for WSO2 Governance Registry

Tags: deployment, sql-server-2012, wso2

Do you have experiences from running WSO2 Governance Registry with SQL Server 2012 (SP1) as a RDBMS? Do you think it will work fine? This is the preferred RDBMS in my organization.

Alternative RDBMSs are MySQL 5x and Oracle 11g. Are there any strong reasons why I would choose one of these alternatives, or yet another alternative, instead of SQL Server?

Answer (score 0):

Ideally any relational database should be possible to use. This would help, http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/display/Governance453/Changing+the+RDBMS

Comment: Yes, I have seen that it is listed among the tested RDBMSs. Still, no version (e.g. 2012 SP1) is specified in this list and also I thought that it may be quirks or issues with some of the RDBMSs which I should be aware of. Maybe there is one RDBMS which is recommended and which used more frequently?